Pronunciation of "il se situe au rez-de-chaussée"
In a lesson on Busuu aimed at B1 learners, there is a vocal clip of a native speaker saying "il se situe au rez-de-chaussée". I have made a very amateurish 17-second video of the speaker's pronunciation of this sentence.
I hear a schwa after the "il". The whole thing (to these untrained ears) sounds like "Il est seau siture au rez-de-chausée."
Has the speaker made a mistake here, and is actually saying "il est situe..."?
https://vimeo.com/1031067828?share=copy
Audio-only clip of just the pronunciation

I think it's important to note that the vocal clip sound very unnatural and is probably either from a text synthesizer or from someone exaggerating pronunciation to an point where it makes it less intelligible than natural speech. It sounds weird even to native speakers, so I wouldn't spend too much time making sense out of it. Especially at B1 level.

Not really an answer but to illustrate existing comments and answers, here are relevant YouTube samples.

se situe au rez-de-chaussée 28"

il se situe au-delà 3'08"

il se situe dores et déjà 19"



Thank you jillagre -- all of those examples are more "comprehensible" to me than the one in my lesson. As others have pointed out a) there are non-standard elements to the stress in the busuu example and b) at B1, it's not worth dissecting too finely. It's just when you're a beginner, you're anxious to copy models accurately.

@Korky I wouldn't say it's non standard. The deviation is way too minimal to be significant. Ask 10 francophones and I bet none of them will pick out that part as odd (see François Jurain's answer that didn't capture it at first), they will just say the guy is speaking slowly and distinctly.

Listening to the audio slowed down, it's quite clear that there is indeed a fully articulated /l/, which is a sign of (overly?) careful speech since the whole phoneme can just as easily be dropped, and there's even a slight schwa /ə/ after it, i.e. a very brief release before the /s/. However, this is far from il est; it's more like he's pronouncing île.
For the /ʀ/ between situe and au, to transition between the front vowel /y/ and the back vowel /o/, the base of the tongue has to jut back sharply. This movement is similar to the beginning of the articulation of /ʀ/ whenever it follows /y/, and (I think) because the articulator has to cover so much distance so fast, it can sometimes be a little imprecise and produce a phantom of that sound.
Addendum: After listening to the samples jlliagre shared, especially « situe au-delà » where there's zero phantom r, I realized that coarticulation could also be playing a role in the sequence /yoʀ/. The tongue begins to partially form an /ʀ/ in anticipation "while it's in the neighbourhood", so to speak.
Incidentally, in that same sample, you can hear a similarly overarticulated /l/, if not quite as strong as in the Busuu audio.

This reminds me of your question where I said there was a nha nhanha factor...

I believe you puzzle at how the speaker realized the u-o hiatus (in situe-au). I hear quite clearly il se situ(e) au rdc, with (e) denoting a half-hearted attempt at inserting a "mute e", definitely not an é, behind the u.
By a half-hearted attempt I mean, a full-hearted one would transcribe s/what like il se situ-euh-au rdc.
To realize a closed e as in your suggestion situ-é-au, the speaker would have to tighten his lips at the corners; more so than to realize the u and the o sounds between which it is uttered. This requires an effort, so he would not do it unconsciously.
Added after question edit:
So, the oddity seems to be how the speaker places accents, more than the u-o hiatus. If so, well spotted!
Speakers are usually focused on the meaning of what they say, so they tend to accent the syllable containing the first consonant of the first word with semantic content of each grammatical unit. Accordingly, the original sentence would normally be uttered like:

'Il-se 'situe-au 'rez-de-chaussée ?

With ' marking the accent: realized by pronouncing the syllable slightly louder, although w/out changing the pitch unlike e. g. English.
What happens here sounds like, the speaker in the video was focused on pronounciation instead of meaning and, careful not to elide the l (i-se instead of il-se as often heard in informal speech), he unconsciously accented se:

Il 'se 'situe-au 'rez-de-chaussée ?

The spurious r sound in siture (if it is not a typo) is an other matter: your hearing might be contaminated by your native tongue.  My hypothesis is, it requires the accent on the first syllable of a grammatical unit, not the first consonant. Accordingly, your natural move would be to accent the sentence as:

'Il-se-situe 'au-rez-de-chaussée?

and, based on accent placement, you parse the unexpected utterance you actually hear as

'Il(e) 'so 'situ 'rau-ez-de-chaussée?


It's more that I hear a shwa after the "il". The whole thing (to these untrained ears) sounds like "Il est seau siture au rez-de-chausée.

Why I'd never guess! You'll help answerers by adding this to your OP.
